# Alternate looping on for and foreach

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have for loop and inside for loop i have foreach loop, All I want is to run for loop once first and then foreach loop and then again for loop and then foreach...

my code is:

```
for (int count = 0; count < countMaster; count++)
{
    foreach (string TemplateName in TemplateList)
    {
        dt.TableName = TemplateName;
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    }
}
return ds;
```

I am trying to use break after the first iteration of foreach loop to go again to the for loop and in the second iteration of foreach it again pass the same value from the loop.

Comment: Something's wrong with an algorithm. Why one could possibly need to iterate through two loops at the same time alternately? Write what do you actually want to happen.

Comment: Actually I am adding rows to the datatable and pass the datable to the dataset on the basis of for loop. datatable.TableName i am getting from the  List and iterating using foreach loop and assign the TableName simultaneously.

Comment: i did not understand  _All I want is to run for loop once first and then foreach loop and then again for loop and then foreach..._  if you mean you want to break after first iterate of foreach then why you use foreach?

Answer (score 1):

In your case the sizes of the lists you are iterating through should be equal, or you should tell us what you really want to do.

But for this specific question you can do:

```
for (int count = 0; count < countMaster; count++)
{
    foreach (string TemplateName in TemplateList)
    {
        dt.TableName = TemplateName;
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        count++;
    }
}
```

**Note:** But I must say this doesn't make much sense. You better try to tell us what you really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do the following to meet your requirement,

```
foreach (string TemplateName in TemplateList)
{
    if (TemplateList.IndexOf(TemplateName) < countMaster)
    {
        dt.TableName = TemplateName;
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but could it be you want to execute once from each loop? Sounds like a Zip operation to me.

```
var xs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var xs2 = new[] { 4, 5, 6 };

var results = xs.Zip(xs2, (i,i2) => i + ":" + i2);
```

Outputs:

```
1:4 
2:5 
3:6
```